# Searching array keys by a string or pattern

Tags: php, regex

I've got some PHP which I'm sure could be done a little more elegantly. It functionally works, so it's more just for self learning.

I have an array (or object) with different alphabetic keys, and I'm looking to find out if a key is set, and if so, to return the remaining match.

The PHP code I have at the moment is just a basic if statement:

```
if(isset($item->revision->application_uid)) $item->type = 'application';
elseif(isset($item->revision->channel_uid)) $item->type = 'channel';
elseif(isset($item->revision->workout_uid)) $item->type = 'workout';
```

So essentially, I'm wanting to search all of the keys, and return the remaining part of the '_uid' key.

[EDIT] Further to this, I've come up with an alternative suggestion, however I'm still wondering if there's a better/more efficient way to do this.

```
foreach(array_keys((array) $item->revision) as $key)
{
    if($match = strstr($key, '_uid', TRUE))
    {
        $item->type = $match;
        break;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a bit duplicated, `foreach` provides the keys already, so you don't need to call `array_keys`:

```
foreach ($item->revision as $key => $value)
{
    if ($match = strstr($key, '_uid', TRUE))
    {
        $item->type = $match;
        break;
    }
}
```

So this does not look that bad. Perhaps you want to initialize with a `NULL` value or some default value in case no type can be found:

```
$item->type = 'none';

foreach ($item->revision as $key => $value)
{
    if ($match = strstr($key, '_uid', TRUE))
    {
        $item->type = $match;
        break;
    }
}
```

Then wrap this into a function of it's own:

```
function findUidKey($item) {

    foreach ($item->revision as $key => $value)
    {
        if ($match = strstr($key, '_uid', TRUE))
        {
            return $match;
        }
    }

    return 'none';        
}
```

And call that function instead:

```
$item->type = findUidKey($item);
```

Further on you can wrap this even inside another class, but perhaps leave that for another time, just start to stick to functions.